# python tkinter scrollbar not aligning properly

Tags: tkinter, scrollbar, python-3.11

I am trying to make a program that will make python easier using OOP, and when I tried to make a horizontal scrollbar. It did not end well

This is my code for the scrollbar:

```
    def add_scrollbar(self, pos1, pos2, orientation, List):

        orientation = orientation.upper()

        if orientation == "HORIZONTAL":
            scrollbar = Scrollbar(self.Created_Window, orient=HORIZONTAL)
            scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        elif orientation == "VERTICAL":
            scrollbar = Scrollbar(self.Created_Window, orient=VERTICAL)
            scrollbar. Pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

        mylist = Listbox(self.Created_Window, yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
        for line in range(len(List)):
            mylist.insert(END, List[line])

        mylist.place(x=pos1, y=pos2)
        scrollbar.config(command=mylist.yview)
```

This the main testing file code:

```
import My Previous code file

Ls = ["line1", "line2", "line3", "line4", "line5", "line6", "line7", "line8"]

easyF = My Previous code file.MyClass()

easyF.create_window("test", "100x100")
easyF.add_scrollbar(250, 250, "horizontal", Ls)
easyF.start_window()
```

This is the image for what happened

[[](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3puvK.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dF372.jpg)

Any ideas why?

Comment: Where is *"the image for what happened"*? BTW for horizontal scrollbar, why is it put at the right side and fill *Y*?

Answer (score 0):

You're explicitly telling the scrollbar to be on the right and fill in the y direction. If it's a horizontal scrollbar, the position would be at the bottom and fill in the x direction.

```
scrollbar = Scrollbar(self.Created_Window, orient=HORIZONTAL)
scrollbar.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
```

Answer (score 0):

The scrollbar does not align properly because you put it at the right side of the window explicitly.  Also `.place()` is used on `mylist` but `pack()` is used on `scrollbar`, and it is hard to align them using different layout functions.

I would suggest to put them in a frame so that they can stick together easily:

```py
def add_scrollbar(self, pos1, pos2, orientation, List):

    orientation = orientation.upper()

    # use a frame to hold the listbox and scrollbar,
    # so they can stick together
    frame = Frame(self.Created_Window)
    frame.place(x=pos1, y=pos2)

    mylist = Listbox(frame)  # create the listbox

    if orientation == "HORIZONTAL":
        scrollbar = Scrollbar(frame, orient=HORIZONTAL, command=mylist.xview)
        scrollbar.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X) # put at bottom side for horizontal scrollbar
        mylist.config(xscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
        mylist.pack(side=TOP) # put listbox above the scrollbar
    elif orientation == "VERTICAL":
        scrollbar = Scrollbar(frame, orient=VERTICAL, command=mylist.yview)
        scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y) # put at right side for vertical scrollabr
        mylist.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
        mylist.pack(side=LEFT) # put listbox at the left side
    else:
        # invalid orientation, raise exception
        raise Exception(f"Invalid orientation: {orientation}")

    for line in List:
        mylist.insert(END, line)
```

Result:

[image]